# Asp.net mvc login cookies other user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've done some changes to my ASP.NET MVC 2.0 application and it started to act strange. I'm looking for a cause, so may you will kow :).

I've added code in Site.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SyneoERPWeb.Helpers" %>
<%

    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
    Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
    Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    Response.AddHeader("Robots", "nofollow, noindex");
    //Response.AddHeader("Last-Modified", DateTime.Now.); = last compilation date
    Response.Buffer = true;

      %>
```

This is very agresive caching for the browser. The problem: I'm singing in as 'test1' and it's working ok. 
I logg off - user is logged of, but browser keeps showing him the main page (as he would be signed in).
I sign in as 'test2', but I'm logged in as 'test1' and still seeing his data.

This situation it this same for every browser.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to clear cache when you sign out.

Comment: @raym0nd: You can't clear the user's browser cache.

Comment: @Slaks, what about page cache ?

Answer (score 0):

The browser is still displaying the cached page from when you were signed in.

If you tell the browser to cache your page, it will listen to you and cache the page, even after you sign out.

You need to use less-aggressive caching.

Comment: ok, you don't have to genius to know that. But how to accomplish this in code?

Comment: @Karol: You need to figure out what caching you want.  Consult the documentation.

Comment: Thank, but I really need a peace of advice. I wan't to cache as content as possible, but don't want this to happed.

Comment: Set the ETag or Last-Modified to a different value if you're logged out.